# IDLTOJAVA compiler

Tags: idl

I am working on an assignment and I believe that the teacher has provided us with outdated instructions because myself and another student are unable to complete steps 1-2 and I was wanting to see if anyone could maybe provide some help with this?  Thank you.

Here are the instructions for steps 1-2:
Step 1: Create an IDL Interface
In this step you will map the IDL to Java in order to define the contract between the server and client for your application. The code for this is language independent and will not look like your traditional Java code. Create a new IDL file using your downloaded IDLTOJAVA compiler. Name the file, “Liberty.idl” and enter the following code:

```
module LibertyApp
{
  interface Liberty
  {
    String libertyU();
  };
};
```

This Liberty U application will only have a single operation. This is all the code that you will need for this step.

Step 2: Mapping Liberty.idl to Java
In this step you will create the required java files through the IDLTOJAVA tool. Open up your command line prompt. Change the directory to the location of your Liberty.idl file. Enter the compiler command: 
idltojava Liberty.idl
You will see that a directory called LibertyApp has been created and it will contain 5 files. Open up Liberty.java. I will contain these lines of code:

```
/* Liberty.java as generated by idltojava */
          package LibertyApp;
          public interface Liberty
              extends org.omg.CORBA.Object {
              String libertyU();
          }
```

I went into visual studio and created a blank file and gave it the Liberty.idl name is that the correct way to create an idl file?

Thank you again!

Comment: The assignment makes absolutely no mention of using Visual Studio. Read them again more carefully.

Comment: Thats the problem though is that the IDLTOJAVA compiler is ancient and wont work on windows 10 so how am I supposed to download it to use it to create the idl file?

Comment: Here is an article I found on the IDLTOJAVA compiler.   http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/904preview/jdk14doc/docs/guide/idl/jidlFAQ.html#where can I download

Comment: It would appear that you should be asking your teacher that question and not us. They gave you the assignment, and would have the specifics about what they're expecting you to do.

Comment: Thats the other problem is that I have emailed and tried contacting the teacher but she wont respond at all to me or the other student and as a last resort i thought I would come here for some help or assistance.